# bx Slider wont stop

Tags: jquery, html, bxslider

I am using the plugin bx slider to control a slideshow. It is set to auto so the slideshow automatically starts.  When I click a custom button (as in not part of the plugin) , I want the slider to stop.  They have a function called stopAuto() but this doesn't do anything.  To boot, he uses things descriptions that kind of make more sense to him.

Here is the link to the plugin [bx slider](http://bxslider.com/options#auto)

And here is my code:

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    pause : 3000,
    autoHover: true
});

// This is just a sample fn, the real one has a different name and a lot more going on in it. So to save space I made this one up.  This will get called with a click on a certain <a> element
function slideshowStop(){
    slider.stopAuto();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/n5hhG/

Answer (score 1):

just set infinite loop attributes to false

```
 $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
     auto: true,
     pause : 3000,
     autoHover: true,
     infiniteLoop: false
 });
```